# Null pointer exception at TextView setText view is inflated

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, textview

I am getting a nullpointer exception when i want to add an object to my list/database. I am inflating the object's xml file, yet it cannot find the TextView. The exception occurs in txtView.setText();

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

protected PhoneDBHelper db;
List<Phone> list;
MyAdapter adapt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new PhoneDBHelper(this);
    list = db.getAllPhones();
    adapt = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_inner_view, list);
    ListView listPhone = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listPhone.setAdapter(adapt);
}

public void addPhoneNow(View v){
    EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String s = t.getText().toString();
    String a = author.getText().toString();
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter the phone name first!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } else {
        Phone phone = new Phone(s, a);
        db.addPhone(phone);
        Log.d("phones", "data added");
        t.setText("");
        author.setText("");
        adapt.add(phone);
        adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Phone>{
    Context context;
    List<Phone> phoneList = new ArrayList<Phone>();
    int layoutResourceId;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Phone> phoneList){
        super(context, layoutResourceId, phoneList);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.phoneList = phoneList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_inner_view, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textBookView);
        Phone current = phoneList.get(position);
        textView.setText(current.getPhoneName() + " - " + current.getAuthor());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

My XML file for the object:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textBookView"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Am i overlooking something? Sorry if this question has already been asked, but I can't find my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you getView method to this:

```
 @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

                if(convertView == null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_inner_view, parent, false);
                }

                TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textBookView);
                Phone current = phoneList.get(position);
                textView.setText(current.getPhoneName() + " - " + current.getAuthor());

                return convertView;
            }
```

convertView is the old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view. Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of view types, so that this View is always of the right type (see getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int)). I got this from here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Comment: It still gives a nullpointerexception, where it first was at the setText, now it cant find the editted line.

Comment: It now gives the exception in 'TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textBookView);'

Comment: can you post the logcat output

Comment: Process: com.example.lucschuttel.appdev50, PID: 27236
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.lucschuttel.appdev50.MainActivity$MyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:96)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2738)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)

Comment: Are you sure the TextView is in the correct xml file ?

Comment: Yes, the xml file is called list_inner_view.xml, with a textview with the id textBookView.

Comment: Sorry for the not so logical variable names

Comment: I changed your getView method this is how it should be :)

Comment: Somebody give this man a cookie :). I added some explanation why your code didn't work before :)